# how to install pg_archivecleanup for postgresql 9.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am trying to get streaming replication working with postgresql 9.3 on Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail). I installed postgresql on master and slave by doing:

> apt-get install postgresql

I believe I have all the bits in place for replication, except, **pg_archivecleanup** does not work. If I attempt to run it, I get it

> The program 'pg_archivecleanup' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: apt-get install postgres-xc-contrib

But that package installs Postgres-XC and blows up my postgresql which I do not wish to do.

The best my googling has come up with is [this thread](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/B6406BD4-59E6-4527-9CA6-A0912374472F@autouncle.com) wherein a guy has the same issue with 9.2 and the only response is "You probably need to install -contrib subpackage as well." But doing:

> apt-get install postgresql-contrib

I get:

> postgresql-contrib is already the newest version.

So how the heck do I get pg_archivecleanup installed for PostgreSQL 9.3 on Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail)?

Thanks!

Brad

Comment: Can you show the result of `apt-cache policy postgresql-contrib`, that may help with the context.

Comment: apt-cache policy postgresql-contrib  
      postgresql-contrib:  
       Installed: 9.3+146really9.2+147.pgdg12.4+1  
       Candidate: 9.3+149.pgdg12.4+1  
       Version table:  
          9.3+149.pgdg12.4+1 0  
             500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg/main amd64 Packages  
      *** 9.3+146really9.2+147.pgdg12.4+1 0  
              100 /var/lib/dpkg/status  
           9.1+140 0  
              500 http://mirror.rackspace.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages

Comment: I can't get that above content to format correctly to save my life.

Answer (score 3):

`postgresql-contrib` is a metapackage that depending on the context leads to the install of `postgresql-contrib-9.3`. The latter contains the files of interest.

Normally if you ran:
`dpkg -L postgresql-contrib-9.3` you should see among the files:

> /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_archivecleanup

It's not in the default PATH, but that's expected.

And in reverse, the command `dpkg -S pg_archivecleanup` should output `postgresql-contrib-9.3`.

The suggestion from the shell's *command-not-found* handler to get it from postgres-xc is just not helpful in this case. Presumably it hits the first package that contains the command name.